# Dynamic textjoin with IF condition lookup from another workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, textjoin

How do i work up the vba code for a Dynamic textjoin with IF condition lookup from another workbook?

I would like to convert this formula into a vba:

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($C$15=[export.XLSX]Sheet1!$E$2:$E$13047,[export.XLSX]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$13047,""))

Currently this is the vba code i have done so far and it is popping up error stating "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

```
Sub join()

Dim exportWb As Workbook
Dim exportWs As Worksheet
Set exportWs = exportWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\desktop\export.xlsx")
Set exportWb = ActiveWorkbook
ThisWorkbook.Activate

Dim exportlastRow1 As Range
Dim exportlastRow2 As Range

exportlastRow1 = exportWs.Cells(exportWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
exportlastRow2 = exportWs.Cells(exportWs.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Dim existSAPID As String
existSAPID = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(C15 = 
exportlastRow2,exportlastRow1,""))")

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You need to reference the workbook before you can reference the worksheet: `Set exportWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\desktop\export.xlsx"): Set exportWs = exportWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. Also, what is the name of the worksheet in `ThisWorkbook` that should contain the formulas? Using `ActiveSheet` is too risky in this case.

Comment: @VBasic2008, name of ThisWorkbook that should contain the formulas = credit assessment; Sheet1

Comment: *"existSAPID"* should be a cell (range) or a one-column range. Which column did you have in mind i.e. if the 'lookup cell' is `C15`, where is the 'return value cell'? One result e.g. for `C15` in `D15`? Or multiple results, for `C15:CLastRow` in `D15:DLastRow`?

Comment: @VBasic2008, my apologies, it should 

Range("C10") = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(C15 = exportlastRow2,exportlastRow1,""))")

let me show u in the screenshot above

Answer (score 0):

### Formula to VBA Code

```vb
Sub JoinMatches()

    ' Source
    Const sFilePath As String = "C:\Test\T2022\72284158\export.xlsx"
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sLookupFirstCellAddress As String = "E2"
    Const sJoinColumn As String = "A"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Credit Assessment"
    Const dLookupCellAddress As String = "C15"
    Const dJoinCellAddress As String = "C10"
    
    ' Reference the source (lookup and join) ranges.
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFilePath)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file '" & sFilePath & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim slrg As Range
    Dim sjrg As Range
    
    With sws.Range(sLookupFirstCellAddress)
        
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        Set slrg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
        Set sjrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(sJoinColumn)
    
    End With
    
    ' Reference the destination join cell.
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim djCell As Range: Set djCell = dws.Range(dJoinCellAddress)
    
    ' Evaluate.
    djCell.Value _
        = dws.Evaluate("TEXTJOIN("", "",TRUE,IF(" & dLookupCellAddress _
        & "='[" & sFileName & "]" & sName & "'!" & slrg.Address _
        & ",'[" & sFileName & "]" & sName & "'!" & sjrg.Address & ",""""))")
    
    ' Close.
    'swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data joined.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: appreciate the help. the code is still showing an error after editing the file directory and the filename:
 "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: sorry i have to idea how to identify which line is throwing the error..

Comment: result is showing #VALUE!, sorry to ask; do we need this lines of code?
 Dim lCell As Range
       Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        Set slrg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
        Set sjrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(sJoinColumn)
    
    End With

Comment: anyone help pls?